# How to clear/reset text field after submitting a record in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

> Sample HTML code

```
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" 
         (click)="saveCustomerOnAction()">Submit</button>
```

> TS code

```
 saveCustomerOnAction() {
const dto = new CustomerDTO(
  this.CustomerId.trim(),
  this.CustomerEmail.trim(),
  Number(this.CustomerMobile.trim()),
  this.CustomerPassword.trim(),
  this.CustomerNic.trim(),
  this.CustomerGender.trim(),
  this.CustomerRole.trim(),
  this.CustomerHiredDate.toString().trim()
);
this.customerService.saveCustomer(dto).subscribe(resp => {
  if (resp.isSaved){
    this.loadAll();
    this.onSucess('Saved!');
  }else{
    this.onWarning('Already Exits');
  }
});
```

}

I want to clear the input fields as soon as the record is saved.

Comment: Do you try form.reset() or resetForm()?:https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm

Comment: In response assign null values such like this `this.CustomerEmail=null`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using reactive forms you can use

Given the fact, CustomerReactiveForm is a Reactive form in your component. After successful submission of your form, then you can do:

```
this.CustomerReactiveForm.reset(this.CustomerReactiveForm.value);
```

if you are using a template-driven form
you can define a reset function and call it in the submit function

```
reset(){
this.CustomerId = null;
this.CustomerEmail= null;
// and so on for the rest of the feilds
}

saveCustomerOnAction() {
const dto = new CustomerDTO(
  this.CustomerId.trim(),
  this.CustomerEmail.trim(),
  Number(this.CustomerMobile.trim()),
  this.CustomerPassword.trim(),
  this.CustomerNic.trim(),
  this.CustomerGender.trim(),
  this.CustomerRole.trim(),
  this.CustomerHiredDate.toString().trim()
);
// call reset here
this.reset();
this.customerService.saveCustomer(dto).subscribe(resp => {
  if (resp.isSaved){
    this.loadAll();
    this.onSucess('Saved!');
  }else{
    this.onWarning('Already Exits');
  }
});
}
```